# Select source from photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, photo

I have `aid` and `user_photo` permission, and I want the photo's source. So I do:

```
select source from photo where id = ID_PHOTO
```

It doesn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

There is NO column `id`

I think you wanted `pid` (wrap photo id in quotes, pid is a string)

```
select src from photo where pid = "ID_PHOTO"
```

[reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/)

EDIT:

It looks like pid isn't working either. Try to use object_id instead if pid wouldn't work.

```
select src from photo where object_id = "ID_PHOTO"
```

Comment: there is no "source" either.  it's "src" -- in any case this wasn't working for me (seemingly a FB bug)

Comment: It's ok. I don't know why i have take source, id and not src, pid. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Jessy if my question helped you, please accept it by ticking it

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API). Here's how it works:

- To get albums: `https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=...`
- To get photos: `https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=...`
- To get the photos in a particular album: `https://graph.facebook.com/*[album_id_here]*/photos?access_token=...`